# authentication failed message when trying to connect hazelcast server with nodejs client application

Tags: node.js, hazelcast

error message:
Connection: Connection{alive=false, connectionId=0, remoteAddress="HZ_ADDRESS:HZ_PORT"} closed. Reason: Authentication failed - Operation did not finish within timeout: 60000

i am using hazelcast client package "hazelcast-client"

code:

```
        let hz_client = await Client.newHazelcastClient({
            clusterName: "dev",
            network:
            {
                clusterMembers: [
                    'HZ_ADDRESS:HZ_PORT'
                ],
                adresses: [
                    'HZ_ADDRESS:HZ_PORT'
                ],
            },
            groupConfig: {
                name: "dev",
            },
        });
```

Comment: What are the versions of the client and the server?
Also, did you change the cluster name of your server? Authentication failure generally results from cluster name mismatches between the client and the server

Comment: I am using latest client v4.0.2 and server v3.12.2. Should the client and server need to have same major version? because i am sure cluster name is correct.

Comment: Yes, the v4 client is only compatible with the 4.x and 5.x servers. You should be using 3.x client to connect 3.x servers.

Also, just a note: In v4 of the Node.js client, the group config element is removed.

Comment: Yes!! thank you. It is working with version 3 client :-)